# Keras TF: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, imdb

Using Keras DL library with Tensorflow backend, I'm trying to implement a batch and validation generator for sentiment analysis with the built-in IMDB dataset.

The dataset contains 25000 training samples and 25000 testing samples. 
Because setting a cut-off for number of words per sample yields a fairly low accuracy, I'm trying to batch the training and testing samples so that the memory load isn't terrible.

Current code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np


max_features = 20000

def generate_batch(batchsize):
'''

'''
(x_train, y_train), (_,_) = imdb.load_data()
for i in range(0, len(x_train), batchsize):
    x_batch = x_train[i:(i+batchsize)]
    y_batch = y_train[i:(i+batchsize)]
    x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=None)
    yield(x_batch, y_batch)

def generate_val(valsize):
'''
'''
(_,_), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data()    
for i in range(0, len(x_test), valsize):
    x_val = x_test[i:(i+valsize)]
    y_val = y_test[i:(i+valsize)]
    x_val = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=None)
    yield(x_val, y_val)

print('Build model...')
primary_model = Sequential()
primary_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = max_features,
                    output_dim = max_features,
                    trainable=False, 
                    weights=[(np.eye(max_features,max_features))], 
                    mask_zero=True))
primary_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(150, use_bias=False)))
primary_model.add(LSTM(128))
primary_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
primary_model.summary()
primary_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
filepath = "primeweights-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True)
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=2)

primary_model.fit_generator(generate_batch(25),
                            steps_per_epoch = 1000,
                            epochs = 1, 
                            callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor],
                            validation_data=generate_val(25),
                            validation_steps=1000)


score, acc = primary_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)

primary_model.save('primary_model_imdb.h5')
```

However, in trying to run the current code, Keras throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "imdb_gen.py", line 94, in <module>
validation_steps = 1000)   
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", 
line 1276, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2224, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1877, in train_on_batch
class_weight=class_weight)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1490, in _standardize_user_data
_check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
File "/home/d/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 220, in _check_array_lengths
'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target 
arrays. Found 25000 input samples and 25 target samples.
```

Comment: This is from a typo in your code: `x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=None)` gives you the whole padded `x_train` which will be 25000 samples. You might want `x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_batch, maxlen=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the code:

- As Pointed out in the comment by @Y. Luo:

```
x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=None) # gives 25000 samples

x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_batch, maxlen=None) # gives batch_size
```

- When loading the imdb dataset you have to give `num_words=max_features` otherwise your embedding layer will expect input max_words as max_features but will end up getting word_ids bigger than that.

```
(x_train, y_train), (_,_) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
```

- It's recommended that while using padding you provide `maxlen` otherwise `maxlen` of batch will be used which might change from batch to batch

```
x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_batch, maxlen=maxlen, padding='post')
```

- You were using your embedding layer without training it and keeping the input and output dimension as same. Didn't make sense to me so I changed that.

```
primary_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = max_features,
                    output_dim = embedding_dim,
                    trainable=True, 
                    weights=[(np.eye(max_features,embedding_dim))], 
                    mask_zero=True))
```

- To evaluate your model on test data you have to load it first and then convert it into padded sequence

```
(_,_), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen, padding='post')
score, acc = primary_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

- While using a Generator for training over multiple epochs, we have to make sure that the generator keeps on yielding values. For this once the data set is over we need to start yielding from 0 again.

```
def generate_batch(batchsize):

    (x_train, y_train), (_,_) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
    print("train_size", x_train.shape)
    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(x_train), batchsize):
            x_batch = x_train[i:(i+batchsize)]
            y_batch = y_train[i:(i+batchsize)]
            x_batch = sequence.pad_sequences(x_batch, maxlen=maxlen, padding='post')
            yield(x_batch, y_batch)
```

Complete working code is linked (updated with fix for point 6) [here](https://pastebin.com/EhYmR6Fk)

Comment: Great, thank you. Regarding the embedding layer, I'm training this model for later use in optimizing input for a given node of the best set of weights. 

With this fixed code, however, the program won't run past the first epoch and stop iterating past that. Any ideas what might be causing this?